# How do I use lft cancellation to solve this problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

Find a binary operation $m$ on $S = \mathbb Z$ which has an identity, is associative and satisfies: $$∀x, y, z ∈ S, m (x, y) = m (x, z) ⇒ y = z$$ but which does not form part of a group structure on $S$.

I have tried to do it this way but I'm unsure if it makes sense specially with the inverse,

Identity: We want to find an element $e$ in $\mathbb Z$ such that for any $x \in \mathbb Z$, $m(x, e) = x$ and $m(e, x) = x$. Let's solve for $e$ in $$m(x, e) = x: x + e + 1 = x\Rightarrow e + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow e = -1$$
So, the identity element is $-1$.

Associativity: $$m(m(x, y), z) = m(x + y + 1, z) = x + y + z + 2\\ m(x, m(y, z)) = m(x, y + z + 1) = x + y + z + 2$$ Associativity holds.
Satisfying the given condition: $m(x, y) = m(x, z)$ implies that $x + y + 1 = x + z + 1$, which simplifies to $y = z$.

Now, let's check whether this operation forms a group structure on $\mathbb Z$:

Closure: Addition is a closed operation on integers, so $m(x, y) = x + y + 1$ is also closed.
Identity: We found that the identity element is $-1$.
Inverses: For each element x, we need to find an element $y$ such that $m(x, y) = -1$ and $m(y, x) = -1$: $$m(x, y) = -1 \Rightarrow x + y + 1 = -1 \Rightarrow y = -x - 2\\ m(y, x) = -1 \Rightarrow y + x + 1 = -1 \Rightarrow y = -x - 2$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1):

You example is incorrect: the integers equipped with $x+y+1\:is$ a group.
The structure you are looking for is a [left-cancellative monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup). The set of nonnegative integers under addition is a cancellative monoid since positive integers do not have an additive inverse. Next, we need to find an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{N},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},\otimes)$, where $\otimes$ is a new binary operation compatible with the isomorphism. For example, let the isomorphism
$f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$ be defined as
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
  -2n  & n \leq 0 \\
  2n-1 & n > 0
\end{cases}$$

The identity in $(\mathbb{Z},\otimes)$ would be $0$, and you could finish by working out the explicit form of the operation $\otimes$.

Comment: Please help with the rest of the solution since I have little knowledge dealing with Monoids

Comment: It's the same as what you do with groups, just make sure $\otimes$ makes $f$ into an isomorphism.